# Deriving from a .NET abstract class in C++, System::IO::TextWriter

Tags: .net, inheritance, c++-cli, abstract-class

I am having an issue where I am making a class that is derived from the abstract class TextWriter.

Documentation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.TextWriter(v=vs.110).aspx

Source
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs

So all the source is in C# and there is this particular piece on lines 160-162 that I need to override for the derived class to not be considered abstract (hinted by a compiler warning):

```
public abstract Encoding Encoding {
    get;
}
```

How would I translate this one part to C++ to override it?

The warning states that 'System::Text::Encoding ^System::IO::TextWriter::Encoding::get(void)' is abstract (as shown in the source of TextWriter), but at the same time when I try to override this "get" function I am given the error that my class contains explicit override 'get' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration.

Here is the only idea for a C++ variant of this function I have had which tells me the "get" function doesn't exist in the base class:

```
  System::Text::Encoding^ Encoding::get(void) {
    return nullptr;
  }
```

The most basic sample displaying this issue:

```
public ref class SampleWriter : public System::IO::TextWriter {
public:

  SampleWriter() {
    // Do Nothing.
  }

  // Need to override 'System::Text::Encoding ^System::IO::TextWriter::Encoding::get(void)'... 
  // Remove this function to see that SampleWriter is inherently abstract and cannot be initialized
  virtual System::Text::Encoding^ Encoding::get(void) override {
    return nullptr;
  }

protected:
  ~SampleWriter() {
    // Do nothing.
  }
};

public ref class SomeForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form {
public:
  SomeForm(void) {
    InitializeComponent();
    sample_writer = gcnew SampleWriter();
  }

protected:
  ~SomeForm() {
    if (components)
      delete components;
  }

private:
  System::ComponentModel::Container^ components;
  SampleWriter^ sample_writer;

  void InitializeComponent(void) {
    this->components = gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container();
    this->Size = System::Drawing::Size(300, 300);
  }
};

int main() {
  SomeForm^ form = gcnew SomeForm();
  form->ShowDialog();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if you use the `property` syntax in the definition of `SampleWriter`? Something like this:

```
property System::Text::Encoding^ Encoding {
    virtual System::Text::Encoding^ get(void) override {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. I never heard of the property syntax in C++ before.

Comment: It's described further in these MSDN articles: [property \(C++ Component Extensions\)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/es7h5kch.aspx) and [How to: Use Properties in C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f1ec0b1.aspx)